# Potentially complicated formula with FILTER, VLOOKUP and multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking at using a filter to pull data from one Google sheet automatically to another Google Sheet.

The problem is, some of the values in the cells contain "," which mismatch my vlookups.

I have figured out the formula I need to automatically filter this, but I can't wrap my head around how to insert it with a filter formula.

**EDIT: The below formulas are on a separate sheet to Data1 & Data2 called "Filter Sheet"**

Here are the two formulas I'd like to combine:

```
=filter('Data2'!C2:C,'Data2'!A2:A="uk")
```

This one cleans up the values with "," in them:

```
if(REGEXMATCH(A8,","),iferror(VLOOKUP(index(split(A8,",",1),1,1),'Data1'!A2:A,1,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(index(split(A8,",",1),1,2),'Data1'!A2:A,1,0),false)))
```

**EDIT:The formula above looks to a different sheet (***Data1***) to see if the "split" result matches the ***VLOOKUP*** on the *current sheet*. If it does not then it goes through a loop to finally find a match on Data1 Sheet.

Essentially, I want the second statement to**

<strike>How do I insert this "clean up formula" so it can work with the filter formula values?</strike>

**EDIT: How can I combine the filter formula with the "if(regex etc. formula" based on the conditions set?**

OR is there an easier way of doing this?

If this helps with an easier method:

The reason why I use a filter formula is because not everything in Data Sheet 1 is found in Data Sheet 2, so this smooths that process out.

Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hi hoco, You're probably asking a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please include your example see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**Try this formula** directly

```
=filter(Data2!C2:C,REGEXEXTRACT(Data2!A2:A, " (uk)")="uk")
```